# Using Node fs.createWriteStream to produce logs, but it is writing duplicates

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Node 0.6.19 with express framework.  I am seeing some weird things with my logging.  First, I created a log for (`createWriteStream`) incoming requests.  I used the express syntax to pipe the requests into the log via:

```
var logFile = fs.createWriteStream('log.log', {
    "flags": "a"
});

app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.logger({
      stream: logFile
    }));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    return app.use(app.router);
});
```

seems to have duplicates of the incoming request when I hit an express route like:

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
```

Second, on some of my routes I do a user lookup in the database, and log the user id to another file by the same `createWriteStream` method.  When I do a

```
logFile.write(user_id + 'n');
```

I get duplicate user_id.  Not a problem with the query itself which tells me something is going on with the `createWriteStream` method.

Answer (score 1):

If using a browser to call your app, you are possibly getting the duplicate output as a result of the `favicon` request. You can easily validate this by intercepting the request using [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or some alternative HTTP debugging proxy depending on your OS.

Comment: Would you see this for any incoming HTTP requests with a favicon?

Comment: I am not sure how different browsers implement this. You are best testing this with a debugging proxy as I suggested. HTH.